# BeagleBoard x15 shows only the last counter number? Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, beagleboard

I use BeagleBoard x15 to show a counter. When I click a button, it will run a loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(i));
    delay(1s);
}
```

But it only showed the last number: '9' on label. It should show: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,...9 after each 1s. I use Qt.

Can you tell me what happen? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused because the application of Qt lives in a loop that your delay blocks, the correct thing is to use a `QTimer`:

```
ui->label->setText("0");
QTimer *timer(this);
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [timer, this](){
    int i = ui->label->text().toInt();
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(i+1));
    if(i == 9)
        timer->stop();
});

timer->start(1000);
```

Comment: In fact, I know that I can use QTimer, but I don't want to use it. I solved that problem: using qApp->processEvents.

Comment: @Colo It is not advisable to do that since other processes can be blocked, perhaps for your current program to work but for one that handles more events does not work correctly.

Comment: I will check my code again. Thank you for your helping.

Comment: @Colo Judging by your comments I think you're not getting it. In event driven environment you never use delay() in GUI thread. Direct reason for label only showing 9 in the end was that widgets are redrawn asynchronously and your application could not do that for nine seconds. Moreover for 9 seconds application was not responding to anything - including user input. Your terrible idea of fixing it by of forcing processing event queue every loop iteration helps to hide the issue and application will respond to pile of events only every second.

Comment: There is another implementation with QEventLoop that can be used with and using the timer, at a time I will publish a new solution

Comment: @ Mariusz Zieliński, so according to you, if I don't want to use Timer (because I used some timers for my application already), what should I do?